Late 90s–early 2000s movie about a woman injected with something that makes her have sex with people and kill them
I'm looking to identify this movie that played on TV around 2007, so it could have been a late '90s or early 2000s movie. It was about a woman injected with something that makes her have sex with people and kill them.
I remember a couple making out in her bedroom, I think, and she heard something at the window, went to look, and got hit by something. I can’t remember if it was an alien creature or just something that gave her a disease, but I remember she started cheating on her boyfriend, having sex with everyone but also killing them. She was like some alien that needed to feed on them.
The boyfriend followed her around the whole movie, trying to save her, and I feel like he was her last victim. 

there are quite a few things that are similar.  Species had a human-looking alien-hybrid who would have sex with man and then kill them. not because she was fed on them or was injected. just part of her reproductive cycle. but this is an old theme, even legendary one. Creatures that appear to men as women and either eat them or feed on their life energy. Vampires and succubi.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

Sound similar to an episode of Torchwood.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabid_(1977_film)

This sounds to me like the second episode of Torchwood:  "Day One."  It aired in 2006, so the timeframe is reasonable.
An alien gas possesses a woman and forces her to have sex with people, thereby absorbing her life energy.  She eventually focuses on her ex-boyfriend.
Per IMDB:

Gwen Cooper is now a member of Torchwood as they investigate a meteor that has crashed on the outskirts of Cardiff. She inadvertently releases a gaseous life form that can take control of a human host. The host is a young woman, Carys, who uncontrollably becomes a sexual predator and any man she has sex with disintegrates. The Torchwood team find her easily but when she manages to escape, they know the lives of young men are at risk.


Some possibilities:

Species (1995) starring Natasha Henstridge is probably the most well-known film of the period you specified featuring this sort of plot

It could also be one of the sequels that Species spawned:

Species II (1998), still starring Natasha Henstridge
Species III (2004), starring Sunny Mabrey
Species: The Awakening (2007), starring Helena Mattsson

Species was a popular movie, and as a result, shortly afterwards, several TV series took the film as inspiration for episodes with similar concepts:

The Outer Limits season 1 episode 15 "Caught in the Act", from 1995, featuring Alyssa Milano
Sliders season 3 episode 19 "The Breeder", from 1997, featuring Kari Wuhrer


None of the Species films line up that closely with this description. The first one is the closest, but the female alien isn't injected by anything and she doesn't have a boyfriend chasing her throughout the film. Also, the description makes it sound like the woman is initially human, not alien, and that something happens to change her. That's not the case with Species.

This could be Liquid Sky, an American independent science fiction film from 1982 directed by Slava Tsukerman and starring Anne Carlisle and Paula E. Sheppard.
From IMDB

Invisible aliens in a tiny flying saucer come to Earth looking for heroin. They land on top of a New York apartment inhabited by a drug dealer and her androgynous, bisexual nymphomaniac lover, who's also a fashion model. The aliens soon find the human pheromones created in the brain during orgasm preferable to heroin, and the model's casual sex partners begin disappearing.

Please see the Wikipedia entry for a more detailed and more accurate synopsis. At first, the model's sex partners merely die, with a mysterious crystal projecting out of their head. But eventually, they disappear upon orgasm.
